# Postgres RDS pg_recvlogical replication role

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication

Im trying to setup a streaming replication on a rds postgresql database using pg_recvlogical. When I send the command to start streaming

```
pg_recvlogical -d <database> -h <host> -p <port> --slot (slot_name) --start -f -
```

I receive the message:

```
"could not send replication command "Show data_directory_mode": ERROR: must be superuser or replication role to run this operation".
```

Im using the master user, which already has superuser role, and set rds.logical_replication to 1 on parameter group associated to the database.
Anyone can help to undestand how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: same here. I think it a bug

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

> Logical replication with pg_recvlogical does currently not work
> correctly on RDS. The workaround is to use a 10.x pg_recvlogical
> client. Since the 'data_directory_mode' parameter was introduced with
> 11.x, a 10.x client will not send the command and hence work fine.

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=936554